# HTML Encoding Not Happening in Apache server

Tags: php, html, apache

I am writting a php code where one of the method returns the following text that will display the image,

```php
$ret = "<div align=\"center\">" .
       "<image src=\"" . "${webserviceDir}Graph.php?usr_id=" . urlencode($usr_id) .
          "&locale_id=" . urlencode($locale_id) . 
          "&session_key=" . urlencode($session_key) . 
          "&websession=" . urlencode($websession) . 
          "&lsweb_moca_service=" . urlencode($lsweb_moca_service) . 
          $service_qualifiers .
          $usr_dash_args .
          "\">" .
       "</div>";
```

**In IIS server this displays the image as expected.**

where as in **Apache server** it returns the following:

*** div align=centerimage src=Graph.php?usr_id=BRUNNERMlocale_id=USsession_key=%3Buid%3%7Csid%3Dv0websession=54deeabc51427e580alsweb_moca_service=http%3A%2F%2F1234%3A4600%2/div ***

As you can see it returned only the string but without the angle brackets "<>".
**I am not sure on why this issue happens only in apache server and not in IIS server**.

Please help.
I want to know the reason on why it behaves like that in APACHE server

Note:
The reason i am using double quotes instead of single quote because i am returning a lot of dynamic informations.

Comment: You are using the double quotes repetedly without concatenation.try out the combination of single and double quotes.something like $ret = '<div align=\"center\">' .'<image src=\"xyz.jpg"\">' .'</div>';

Comment: You have 1 double quote too much here: `"<image src=\"xyz.jpg"\">"` remove it to this: `"<image src=\"xyz.jpg\">"`. Does that do the trick?

Comment: Please show us the full code then how you use it!

Comment: Thanks for the reply;Please check the question again i have edited it again to give a clear picture of the issue. I want to know the reason on why it behaves like that in APACHE server because in IIS it works fine.

Comment: Can you tell what versions of PHP is used by Apache and IIS?

Comment: Instead of "image src" use "img src" and could you please attach output of ${webserviceDir}

Comment: The output of ${webserviceDir} is  http://localhost/test/Graph.php

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use single quote instead of escaping `"` -

```
$ret = "<div align='center'>" .
   "<image src='" . "${webserviceDir}Graph.php?usr_id=" . urlencode($usr_id) .
      "&locale_id=" . urlencode($locale_id) . 
      "&session_key=" . urlencode($session_key) . 
      "&websession=" . urlencode($websession) . 
      "&lsweb_moca_service=" . urlencode($lsweb_moca_service) . 
      $service_qualifiers .
      $usr_dash_args .
      "'>" .
   "</div>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply;Please check the question again i have edited it again to give a clear picture of the issue. I want to know the reason on why it behaves like that in APACHE server because in IIS it works fine.

Comment: you can still use `'` instead of `\"`